# Calculating $\int_{S^{n-1}}x_1^2dS$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, gamma-function

Denote $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$. I want to calculate the following integral: $$\int_{S^{n-1}}x_1^2dS$$

Where $S^{n-1}$ is the $n$ dimensional sphere.

I was given a hint to use the fact that the volume of $S^{n-1}$ is $\frac{2\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}$, but I couldn't think of a way to use it.

Comment: The answer is the same as for [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3190117) integral.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? I'm not sure I understand you

Comment: Look at the comments under the other question. Or consider the simplest case $\int x ds$ over the unit circle.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I accidently wrote $x_1$ instead of $x_1^2$, I edited the question.

Comment: Big Hint, the integral is the same if you replace $x_1^2 dS$ with  any  $x_k^2 dS$

Comment: Maybe by using linearity of the integral, I can claim that the sum of the integrals $x_k^2$ is just the surface area of the sphere, and then divide it by $n$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. How can I formally claim that the integrals are equal?